# Rate of decrease of the Fourier transform of standard mollifiers

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, fourier-transform

What is the the rate of decrease of $|\widehat{f_p}(t)|$ (as $t\to\infty$), where $p\in(0,\infty)$,
$$\widehat{f_p}(t):=\int_{\mathbb R} e^{itx}f_p(x)\,dx,$$
and
$$f_p(x):=e^{-1/(1-x^2/p)^p}1(|x|<\sqrt p),$$
so that $f_p\in C^\infty$, $f_p'(0)=0$, and $f_p''(0)=-2/e$ for all $p$.

Here are the graphs $\{(x,f_p(x))\colon|x|<\sqrt p\}$ for $p=1$ (red), $p=2$ (green), and $p=3$ (blue):

[image]

The decrease seems to be very fast, almost to $0$ in a finite time $t>0$. Below are parts of the graphs of the functions $\ln\ln\dfrac1{|\widehat{f_p}|}$ for $p=1$ (red), $p=2$ (green), and $p=3$ (blue):

[image]

This seems to almost contradict [Hardy's uncertainty principle](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/hardys-uncertainty-principle/) -- which implies, as noted in Dmitry Krachun's comment, that $\widehat{f_p}(t)$ cannot decay faster than $e^{-ct^2}$ for any $c>0$.

Comment: I think the function $f_{p}$ never vanishes, as it is defined as an exponential of something.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, since $f$ is compactly supported, Hardy's uncertainty principle implies that $\hat{f}$ cannot decay faster than $e^{-\epsilon t^2}$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @DmitryKrachun : Good point.

Comment: The Fourier transform of the Lévy distribution, $a x^{-3/2} \exp(-1/x)$, decays as $\exp(-b\sqrt{|t|})$ as $|t| \to \infty$. This suggests a similar decay rate for the Fourier transform of $f_p$ with $p = 1$. Other one-sided stable distributions may give a hint what to expect for other values of $p$, but I do not quite remember their behaviour at $0$, and unfortunately I have no time to look it up now.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki : Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN $f_p$ vanishes when $|x|$ is sufficiently large with respect to $p$.  The point is that $\exp(-|x|)\to 0$ as $|x|\to\infty$.

Comment: I think Theorem A in [*Transition densities of subordinators of positive order*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.06793) by my colleagues Tomasz Grzywny, Karol Szczypkowski and Bartosz Trojan shows that the density is of the order $a x^{-(2-\alpha)/(2-2\alpha)} \exp(-b x^{-\alpha/(1-\alpha)})$ while the Fourier transform decays as $\exp(-|t|^\alpha)$. So I expect that the Fourier transform of $f_p$ decays roughly as $\exp(-|t|^{p/(p+1)})$. (The result for stable densities is much older, I guess, this is just the first reference that came to my mind.)

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki : Thank you for your further comment.

Comment: I can prove an upper bound rougly of the form that's written in @MateuszKwaśnicki comment. If it's of interest for you I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov : Yes, of course -- please do post your answer. I will be looking forward to it.

Answer (score 3):

So, morally, the only real way to bound the decay of $\hat{f}$ is to obtain some bounds on the derivatives of $f$. Let me do a little dilation and consider $f(x) =  \exp(-1/(1-x)^p - 1/(1+x)^p)$, it does a well-known thing on the Fourier side and doesn't affect general decay properties. And fortunately for us, bounds for the derivatives of this function were written out by Arie Israel in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04404) beautiful paper (I think it's a third time I've given this reference to someone, see also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362121/a-question-about-schwartz-type-functions-used-in-analytic-number-theory) MO question for related matters). Specifically, Lemma 2 of his paper says that

$$|f^{(k)}(x)| \le (16p)^k k^{(1+1/p)k}.$$
(he considers the case $p\in \mathbb{N}$ but his methods should work for any $p > 0$).

We have
$$|\hat{f}(\xi)| \le 2\frac{||f^{(k)}||_{L^\infty}}{|\xi|^k}.$$
Factor of $2$ here is because $\text{supp} f = [-1, 1]$ has length $2$ and there also might be some powers of $2\pi$ thrown here and there depending on the normalization of the Fourier transform. Neither of those will affect our argument of course.

Combining this with the above estimate we get

$$|\hat{f}(\xi)| \le 2 \left(\frac{16p k^{(1+1/p)}}{|\xi|}\right)^k.$$

We want to choose $k\in \mathbb{N}$ so that the number in the brackets is some constant, say it's at most $\frac{1}{2}$ and at least $\frac{1}{4}$ (this can always be done for $|\xi|$ big enough). This gives us
$$|\hat{f}(\xi)| \le 2^{1-k}.$$
On the other hand we have $$k \ge \left(\frac{|\xi|}{64p}\right)^{p/(p+1)},$$
which gives us the desired decay in terms of $|\xi|$ of the form $$|\hat{f}(\xi)|\le A\exp(-B|\xi|^{p/(p+1)})$$
for some $A, B>0$.

Note that $\hat{f}$ can't have exponential decay because otherwise $f$ would be analytic in a strip and thus not compactly supported; one can actuallly deduce even more from the general results, see Denjoy-Carleman Theorem and Beurling-Malliavin Theorem in my answer to the above MO question. But here I think it is probable that the above decay is the correct one up to the values of $A$ and $B$: indeed, if $\hat{f}$ decays very fast then we can obtain better pointwise bounds on the derivatives of $f$ and the Israel's bounds are probably sharp, although I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Apparently, I can’t do simple arithmetic and the function I considered is not directly related to the one from the OP. I will write an edit later today