# Is my application of Faà di Bruno's formula correct?

Tags: co.combinatorics, fa.functional-analysis

Suppose I have a function $f$ from $\mathbb R^d$ to $\mathbb R$, and denote $g = \exp \circ f$.

I want to express the derivatives of the function $g$ in term of the derivatives of $f$ and vice versa, so I need to do two applications of Faà di Bruno's formula, on $\exp$ and $\ln$. I obtain:

$$f^{(\mathbf i)}(\mathbf t) = \sum\limits_{\pi \in \Pi(\mathbf i)} g(\mathbf t) \prod\limits_{B \in \pi} g^{(\mathbf i(B))}(\mathbf t)$$
    $$g^{(\mathbf i)}(\mathbf t) = \sum\limits_{\pi \in \Pi(\mathbf i)} (\lvert \pi \rvert - 1)! (-1)^{\lvert \pi \rvert - 1} f(t)^{-\lvert \pi \rvert} \prod\limits_{B \in \pi} f^{(\mathbf i(B))}(\mathbf t)$$

Where I denoted:

- $\mathbf i$ a multi-index representing the number of derivations in each dimensions
- $B(\mathbf i)$ is a simple map from e.g $\mathbf i = (1,0,2)$ to $B(\mathbf i) = (1,3,3)$ giving the blocks, and $\mathbf i(B)$ is the reverse map.
- $\Pi(\mathbf i)$ is the set of partitions of $B(i)$

Could you tell me if you see a obvious mistake ? (also, I have trouble tagging the question properly)

Comment: You need to explain your notations. Right now you are asking the reader to guess the correct formulation of what you meant to say. I can guess that $B(\mathbf{i})$ is a choice of multiset where $1$ appears $\mathbf{i}_1$ times, $2$ appears $\mathbf{i}_2$ times, etc. But what is a partition of $B(\mathbf{i})$?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam $B(\mathbf i)$ is exactly the set you wrote. A partition of a set $A$ is a set of disjoint blocks $A_i$ included in $A$ such that their union is $A$.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to write the Faa di Bruno formula, some good and some bad.
For functions of one variable, a good way to write it can be found in my answer to the MO question

[Gevrey estimate of derivatives](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268389/gevrey-estimate-of-derivatives)

It says,
$$
(f\circ g)^{(n)}(t)=n!\sum_{k\ge 0}\ \sum_{n_1,\ldots,n_k\ge 1}
\mathbf{1}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{k} n_i=n\right\}
\ \frac{f^{(k)}(g(t))\ g^{(n_1)}(t)\cdots g^{(n_k)}(t)}{k!\ n_1!\cdots n_k!}
$$
where $\mathbf{1}\{\cdots\}$ stands for the indicator function of the condition within braces.
Now suppose the inner function $g$ is now a function from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
Then the Faa di Bruno is exactly the same but with a little twist as to the interpretation of $n$, $n_1$, etc. Let $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ to clarify my choice of conventions. Now of course $t=(t_1,\ldots,t_d)\in\mathbb{R}^d$, but more importantly
$n$, $n_1$, etc. are multiindices, i.e., elements of $\mathbb{N}^d$. For a multiindex $p=(p_1,\ldots,p_d)\in\mathbb{N}^d$, we let by convention
$$
p!=p_1!\cdots p_d!
$$
and
$$
g^{(p)}(t)=\frac{\partial^{p_1+\cdots+p_d}}{\partial t_1^{p_1}\cdots\partial t_d^{p_d}}g(t)\ .
$$
Another modification is that $n_1,\ldots,n_k\ge 1$ now means none of these multiindices is $(0,\ldots,0)$.

It is now straightforward to specialize the formula to $\exp$ or $\log$.

Comment: So, in the $\mathbb R^d$ case, you mean that the LHS is now $(d/dx_1)^{n_1}\cdot \cdot \cdot (d/dx_d)^{n_d}$ right? And do you have a source for this? (I trust you I just need a source too, but I only find it in terms of counting permutations, which I find hard to get my head round, and the Wikipedia article seems to specialise to $n_1=\cdot \cdot \cdot =n_d$). Quite possible I'm misunderstanding something though.

Comment: And actually, even in the $d=1$ case, I'm not sure how it matches up with the Wikipedia article's statement. Apologies! How do you group the terms?